# Clang On Windows give errors when trying to compile with Winsock headers

Tags: c, clang, winsock

is it possible to use Winsock on Clang when compiling from Windows?

My Include headers are: They seem to resolve correctly. but not comppile

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#else
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#endif
```

I am getting errors and unable to find a way to fix this on the internet

```
C:\Code>clang-cl vivotool.c http.c  -DWIN32 -o vivotool.exe
In file included from http.c:2:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\windows.h:164:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\shared\windef.h:24:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\shared\minwindef.h:182:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(1245,0) : error: function definition declared 'typedef'
EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION
^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(1247,0) : error: parameter named 'EXCEPTION_ROUTINE' is missing
EXCEPTION_ROUTINE (
^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(1254,8) : error: unknown type name 'EXCEPTION_ROUTINE'
typedef EXCEPTION_ROUTINE *PEXCEPTION_ROUTINE;
        ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(1254,0) : error: invalid storage class specifier in function declarator
typedef EXCEPTION_ROUTINE *PEXCEPTION_ROUTINE;
^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(1254,27) : error: parameter named 'PEXCEPTION_ROUTINE' is missing
typedef EXCEPTION_ROUTINE *PEXCEPTION_ROUTINE;
                           ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(2144,0) : error: invalid storage class specifier in function declarator
typedef ULONG_PTR KSPIN_LOCK;
^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(2144,18) : error: parameter named 'KSPIN_LOCK' is missing
typedef ULONG_PTR KSPIN_LOCK;
                  ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(2145,8) : error: unknown type name 'KSPIN_LOCK'
typedef KSPIN_LOCK *PKSPIN_LOCK;
        ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(2145,0) : error: invalid storage class specifier in function declarator
typedef KSPIN_LOCK *PKSPIN_LOCK;
^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(2145,20) : error: parameter named 'PKSPIN_LOCK' is missing
typedef KSPIN_LOCK *PKSPIN_LOCK;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error list says that http.c has an #include for windows.h.  That does not appear to match the snippet at all.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask], then provide a [example]. Only then we might be able to help you.